# Excel VBA script optimization - traversal algorithm - solve this puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, vba, sorting, loops, traversal

I have a somewhat large excel workbook with several sheets. The workbook records employee expenses.

I have a vba macro that loads data from a master sheet to all the other sheets and it is taking a very long time to run. I was hoping to get some tips on how I might be able to improve the performance.

**Some quick background info:**
Each employee has an individual sheet. This sheet contains all the expenses for that employee for each month of the year - January through December (columns). There can be many types of expenses (rows).

The master data sheet contains all the expenses for all the employees for the year. Each record contains the employee id (which is used as the employee's sheet name), expense type, expense amount and date. The master sheet is sorted by employee id, then date, then expense type. There can be duplicate expense types for the same date.

Though there can be duplicate expense types on the master data sheet, there are no duplicates on the employee sheet. The expenses are summed for each type for each month.

Example - master sheet:

```
> EmpID1 ExpenseType1 01/02/2015 $5
> EmpID1 ExpenseType2 01/02/2015 $3
> EmpID1 ExpenseType2 01/03/2015 $6
> EmpID1 ExpenseType2 01/03/2015 $10
> EmpID1 ExpenseType2 01/04/2015 $11
> ...
```

Example - employee sheet:

```
> Months up top: Jan Feb Mar Apr May ...   
> ExpenseType1 $5 $2 $10 $3 $2
> ExpenseType2 $30 $5 $1 $32 $12 
> ExpenseType3 $11 $22 $3 $1 $2
> ...
```

**The problem:**
What is the best way to populate the employee sheets?

My current algorithm traverses the master data sheet once by reading each record. But it then traverses the employee sheet multiple times. It looks for that expense type on the employee's sheet and adds the amount to the previous.

Is this the most optimum solution? Any ideas on how I might be able to improve on this please?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on why you need to traverse an individual employee sheet multiple times?

Comment: It would help a lot to show your existing code.  It's easier to follow that for details than a textual explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, regardless of your data collection and manipulation algorithm, you can speed up the process IMMENSELY by first preparing the data in a multi-dimensional array, and then using the .Range VBA method to populate a given range with your array.

The key to this is that you write out the array to a range all at once, not cell by cell.  I am assuming that right now you are doing a lot of individual cell manipulations, such as getting a piece of data from one cell, putting it into another, etc.  The actual interaction between excel cell manipulations and VBA is actually quite slow (not sure why, but probably due to cascading cell functions and visual updates, but see https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx for more information on Excel+VBA speed and efficiency rules and examples).

More info on how to use arrays and ranges: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx
By the way, C Pearson has a lot of great information on Excel+VBA, so I highly recommend his site as a general reference.

I have used this before and sped up a macro from an order of minutes to an order of seconds.  Hopefully it can do the same for you.

---

Edit: I don't know what your current data manipulation algorithm is, so I can't comment directly on that yet, but if it is for the summation of expenses, can you try to sum up the data as you go, so that way you don't need to do any extra calculations by the time you get to the sheet you simply have to input the data in the correct month columns?

Comment: I havent seen this method before. So are you putting the whole data in memory (array) and then processing everything in there first? Then write out the results to the sheet?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  I will update my answer shortly to provide some more references/info on ranges and arrays

Comment: Thanks for that link! I didnt know about this. I'm browsing through that site but is it faster to dump an array to a column rather than traversing each element of the array and writing to each cell of the column? Isnt the first approach writing to each cell anyways?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% sure why.  My guess would be that Excel also stores its data in a multidimensional array and therefore its easier to splice the data from their structures than it is to go through a GUI based system (since manipulating cells triggers functions and other visual updates).  For more info, check out this link on Excel+VBA efficiency: https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx

Lastly, fun fact: using 3D arrays lets you copy+paste data over multiple sheets